# Spark: Connection refused webapp proxy on yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, docker, hadoop-yarn, network-interface

I am using spark and hadoop on docker container:
I have 3 container master and 2 slave.

Everything is working properly but I have problem with spark proxy webapp when running a task.

I can connect to yarn webapp though n`http://172.20.0.2:8088/`
I can also acces the nodes with `http://172.20.0.3:8042/node` and `http://172.20.0.3:8043/node`

But when tring to access spark monitoring with this address `http://172.20.0.2:8088/proxy/application_1521727348200_0001/` I get

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /proxy/application_1521727348200_0001/. Reason:

    Connection to http://hadoop-slave2:8088 refused
Caused by:
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://hadoop-slave2:8088 refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.proxyLink(WebAppProxyServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.doGet(WebAppProxyServlet.java:387)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:900)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:142)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RMAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1243)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    ... 50 more
Caused by:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.proxyLink(WebAppProxyServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServlet.doGet(WebAppProxyServlet.java:387)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:900)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.doFilter(RMWebAppFilter.java:142)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:795)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter.doFilter(StaticUserWebFilter.java:109)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RMAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer2.java:1243)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I think that the problem is related to network interfaces;
First of all I am using docker network overlay and not a bridge. If I use a bridge I can access the monitor via localhost or the public address of the container

When I have used overlay the first time I couldn't even access yarn webapp (I get connection refused)

When I am in the container all this command give me connection refused

```
wget localhost:8088/
wget 172.18.0.2:8088/
```

but this one works

```
wget 10.0.0.2:8088/
```

So I had to add this to `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
</property>
```

The problem was related to the network interface because I have this in the same file.

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
<value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
```

and `hadoop-master` is the hostname of this address `10.0.0.2`.

after changing `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` I can access the 8088 port from all network interfaces but I couldn't access spark monitoring like I have explained above.

***Udapte :***

I have notice another thing if I use 
`wget http://hadoop-master:8088/proxy/application_1521730349211_0003/`inside the container I get the correct index.html page without any error.

So The problem is indeed related to networks interfaces.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

HDFS and Yarn seem to struggle without hostnames known to all members

Make sure you have all your ip+hostname in /etc/hosts on all hosts and finally:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:8088</value>
</property>
```

needs to be:

```
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>hostname:8088</value>
</property>
```

see this:
[Hadoop2- YARN - ApplicationMaster UI - Connection refused issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176322/hadoop2-yarn-applicationmaster-ui-connection-refused-issue)