# Spark: is using wrong network interface

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, docker, pyspark, network-interface

I am using a hadoop cluster inside a docker containers (I am using overlay network)

I have 2 containers in the same host (master and slave2)
and another in a different host (slave1)

The containers can access a local network that is only used by them `10.0.0.0`

The master and slave2 container can also access another network that is shared with the host `172.18.0.0`

Slave1 can access a different network `172.18.0.0` that is shared with its host

the network `172.18.0.0` in the two hosts are independent.

So to resume every container has two ip address

- master: `10.0.0.2` and `172.18.0.2`
- salve2: `10.0.0.3` and    `172.18.0.3`
- salve3; `10.0.0.4` and `172.18.0.2`

The tree container must communicate trow 10.0.0.0 network. but there is something strange happening.

when I run this script in pyspark

```
def getIP(iter):
  import socket
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
  return [s.getsockname()[0]]


rdd = sc.parallelize(range(3),3)
hosts = rdd.mapPartitions(getIP).collect()
for h in hosts:
  print(h)
```

the output of this problem is

```
172.18.0.2
172.18.0.3
172.18.0.3
```

which is wrong because the containers can only communicate throw 10.0.0.0 network interface.

this is my `yarn-site.xml` file

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>
            yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class
        </name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoop-master</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-master is a hostname for the address `10.0.0.2`

How can I tell spark to use 10.0.0.2 interface.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your spark uses wrong network, otherwise you cannot even run this program.

Your `getIP` method returns ip the host used to connect `8.8.8.8`. As you described, all hosts have two networks while `10.0.0.*` is only shared by these 3 nodes. So the hosts use `172.18.0.*` to connect `8.8.8.8`.

You can try to see the difference between `s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))`, `s.connect(("10.0.0.2", 80))` and `s.connect(("localhost", 80))`.

Comment: So I was wrong I didn't pay attention to the script. I have though that is script give me the interface that the cluster use to communicate between each other. this was my main problem could you take a look  https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/issues/251

Comment: take a look at your issue. I don't think it's related to spark or your configuration. The project owner doesn't consider multi network and use a simple way to get ip address to bind: https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/blob/master/tensorflowonspark/util.py#L13 maybe you can report this and create a pr :)

Comment: now I see thank you very much I really appreciated I was searching for a solution the whole day. I was thinking this is related to my configuration because I have also this problem with spark 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432142/spark-connection-refused-webapp-proxy-on-yarn